# Where to add CPU Instructions Installing Tensorflow From Source?

Tags: python, terminal, tensorflow, cpu, sse

I am trying to install Tensorflow from source because of a warning about CPU instructions (SSE, AVX...) not being installed when I installed with pip AND virtualenv:

`W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.`

So I'm trying to install Tensorflow from source so that these instructions can be compiled with Tensorflow.

1. Do I need to do anything aside from the instructions on the Tensorflow website to compile with these instructions? (`./configure`?)
2. If so, what do I need to do and how exactly do I do it?
3. In the installation when I have to install the pip package, the Tensorflow website says that for Linux, the command is :
   `sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-py2-none-any.whl`it says that this command will differ based on the machine, what is the equivalent command for MacOS? How do I go about the Bazel `wheel`steps?

Side Note: I've been told that there are a few ways I could do this with Bazel, but being unexperienced with Bazel and not too experienced on Terminal, I need clear steps on what to do?

OS Sierra (10.12.2)

Comment: From a deleted answer: pre-built optimized binaries: https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build

Answer (score 1):

For your question number one (and two), the default for ./configure will provide you with the instruction set optimized for your machine. This is done through the default compiler option, `-march=native`. Just follow the steps [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)

For number three, once you have generated the `whl` file in `/tmp/tensorflow_pkg` (or where ever), then look at the name of the file in that directory. It will be similar to but different than the linux example given in the instructions. You should then be able to install it using`pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/YOUR_FILENAME.whl`. If you have any problems you can follow steps [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) but using `/tmp/tensorflow_pkg/YOUR_FILENAME.whl` instead of `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX you can just do

```
brew install tensor-flow
```

I believe.